# How do you set up port forwarding in Azure Web App for Xero oauth

Tags: azure, xero-api, azure-webapps

We have an on premise website connected to Xero.
The port used in the redirect uri was opened on the server and it all plays nicely.

We are in the process of moving to Azure, I have uploaded the database and installed the website in to a web app. I cannot find anyway to set up port forwarding in Azure for the web app.

Has anyone any experience of this or have all of the Xero oauth working in Azure web app or other options.

Any help greatly appreciated

Everything works in on premise so I think the only issue is the redirect uri.

From Azure, the app opens Xero.com and allows me to log in, it is when it is meant to pass the token back to the web app that Xero errors with a timeout.

I have tried the AD Active directory for the web app, there is a redirect uri but it looks like it is used to define uri's for sending out a token rather than receiving one.

I am hoping someone has experience and can save me days or reading and trial and error to set this up.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Xero follows [standard OAuth flows](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/auth-flow), after you have logged in, you should be redirected back to the `redirect_uri` where you either get the token or the code you can use to exchange for a token. The `redirect_uri` has to be accessible from your browser (not Xero). Your `redirect_uri` should be an URL from your Azure app, like `https://your-azure-app/oauth2/callback`.

Comment: The redirect uri is back to azure. In Azure my site is in a web app slot which appears to have limited options on opening ports. I was hoping someone else may have already found a way around this. I think the answer is going to be a VM hosting the website instead which should give me the control I need. My other sites which do not connect to Xero are all working in app slots.